# class ShellTile not found

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a big problem in the use of the class ShellTile. I've already done several research on  tutorials but they can't answer my question.
The problem appears when I want to use "ShellTile" or "StandardTileData" to manipulate the tiles of the application, I have the error "the name ShellTile doesn't exist in the contest" or "A namespace is missing?"..

I made a new project, I add "using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;" at the beginning and I verify if "Microsoft.Phone" was adding in References. But the problem is already the same...

Where does it come from ? I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone gratis...

Xavier

Comment: You can always try reinstalling VS Express and WP SDK...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ShellTileData` has been added with Windows Phone 7.1 (Mango). Make sure that you're targeting the right version of the framework.

To check which version you're targeting, right click on the project, click on 'properties', go in the 'Application' tab, and ensure that 'Windows Phone OS 7.1' is selected in the 'Target Windows Phone OS version' list.

[image: Select Windows Phone OS version]

If the list doesn't appear, then you're probably using an outdated version of the SDK.

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't have this list so I will update my version of the SDk